# Issue with oozie workflow submitting sh to launch spark2 job

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-2.0

Let me explain the issue, it's turning me crazy...

I have a spark2 program that I want to submit from an oozie workflow.

Because spark2 by default cannot be submitted directly from oozie, I have created an sh with the spark2-submit sentence to execute the spark2 job.

If I run this sh from the console it works perfect. However, when I run it from the oozie workflow, there is no way to make it work, but the worse is I cannot see a clear error on logs returned by the execution.

These are the files I am using:

**thintest.sh:**

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --class main hdfs:///home/cloudera/thintest/thintest-assembly-0.1.jar
```

**job.properties**

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
dryrun=False
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
jobTracker=quickstart.cloudera:8032
security_enabled=False
hiveXml=/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
appName=thintest
appPath=${nameNode}/home/cloudera/thintest
oozie.wf.application.path=${appPath}/workflow.xml
shellPath=${appPath}/thintest.sh
```

**workflow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app name="thintest" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">

<start to="shell"/>

  <action name="shell">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">

      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

      <exec>${shellPath}</exec>
      <env-var>HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}</env-var>
      <file>${shellPath}#thintest.sh</file> 

    </shell>

    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="kill"/>

  </action>

  <kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
  </kill>

  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-2-on-YARN-via-Oozie-Hue-wrong-version/td-p/64495 >> you can set up a specific Oozie "ShareLib" for Spark2, and define your Spark actions so that they use the specific "ShareLib" -- but Cloudera does provide that feature out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie has a spark-2 profile and the Spark action in Oozie works perfectly fine after Oozie is built with it.

I wouldn't recommend hacking around the shell action as it will turn into a nightmare sooner or later.